# Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in... with Cakephp

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I can´t import facebook SDK with cakephp 2.x. The class never exist. My route is: app/Vendor/FacebookSdk/src/Facebook/facebook.php (checked)

Mi AppController:

```
public function beforeRender() {
        parent::beforeRender();
        App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array(
            'file' => 'FacebookSdk' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'facebook.php')
        );

       if (class_exists('Facebook')) {
            if (method_exists('Facebook', 'getLoginUrl')) {
                $this->set('fb_login_url', $this->Facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    'scope' => array('public_profile, email, user_birthday'),
                    'redirect_uri' => Router::url(array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'acceso_publico'), true)
                    ))
                );
            }
        }
        $this->set('userFacebook', $this->Auth->user());
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'acceso_publico');

    }
```

What's wrong?, I see it all right

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In such non-standard cases I find it way easier to just require_once the file.

```
require_once APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'FacebookSdk' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'facebook.php';
```

This has the added benefit, that you'll actually get an error message in the case the file is not found.

For a cleaner solution, I'd recommend using composer in your project, as it will handle autoloading these files. Here are instructions, this takes 10 minutes to set up and saves you a lot of hassle.

[Installing CakePHP with composer](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer)